# Update a value in a nested field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
user :["id": 1, userObj:[{"bookid": 1, "library":"Oxford", "taken":true}, {"bookid": 2, "library":"Cambridge", "taken":true}]]
```

I would like to update the value taken and set it to false for the bookid.

```
   tmp = await User.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body.id},  { $elemMatch: {'userObj.bookid': req.body.bookid }, { $set: { 'userObj.taken': false }, }, { new: true } )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use positional operators

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1,
  "userObj.bookid": 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "userObj.$.taken": false //$ is a positional operator which updates the matching array element
  },
  
})
```

[Playgroun](https://mongoplayground.net/p/55DYX6Mkopa)